# How to store previous activity value in android?

Tags: android

How to store previous `activity` value in `android`

Comment: +1 for a clear and detailed question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent mainIntent = Intent(ThisActivity.this, UpComingActivity,class);
mainIntent.putExtrat("To Store", "Value");
```

Afterwards then getExtra can be used with the KeyValue for getting the OutCome.

Answer (score 2):

Could you describe your use case? Do you want to get the return value when you started your activity with startActivityForResult? Or maybe you want to know what was the activity that started your one? Or is it sth else?